# Band-pass filter simulation

Tags: ltspice, simulation, band-pass, cutoff-frequency

Passive band-pass filter simulation on LTspice. Given: cutoff frequencies F<sub>low</sub>= 10 kHz and F<sub>high</sub>= 22 kHz. The run isn't getting me -3 dB between the pass.

I calculated R and C and put them in the simulation, but when I click run the values are wrong.

[image]

It must have the values of cut-off frequencies at -3 dB.

What mistake did I make?

Comment: @JessieRaya Two things: 1) the -3 dB point is *relative* to the passband, and 2) you are using an *unbuffered* RC filter, which means you'll need to account for the loading effect (the transfer function differs than the buffered one). Also, don't forget that you used `AC 10`.

Comment: I didn't understand what i did wrong

Answer (score 2):

No, you won't get a -3 dB point with your filter because the low-pass and high-pass  cut-off frequencies are too close to each other. Given that your AC signal is 10 volts, I'd expect a properly designed band-pass filter to peak at about 20 dBV on the output but, yours peaks at about 16.5 dBV hence, it doesn't quite reach 17 dBV (the -3 dB point).

There are also impedance interactions between the low-pass and high-pass filter circuits and, this might muddle things up a little.

> *What mistake did I make?*

Try plotting low-pass and high-pass circuits individually on the same graph and you should be able to see what I mean. You could also experiment with spreading the low-pass and high-pass cut-off frequencies and you will see that the band-pass section will inevitably get closer to 20 dBV on the output.

In future, use an AC signal strength of 1 to make it easier on the numbers.